# .NET - Converting Color Name Strings into System.Drawing.Color

Tags: .net, colors, system.drawing.color

What is the best way to turn strings like "red", "green", "yellow", "aliceblue", etc... into the actual System.Drawing.Color value?

I was looking at reflection and something about that didn't seem right.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use Color.FromName()

Answer (score 24):

System.Drawing.Color has a static method:

```
public static Color FromName(string name)
```

Use it like so:

```
   Color c = Color.FromName("AliceBlue")
```

Answer (score 12):

System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Red");

Comment: System.Drawing.Color is a struct, no enum.

Comment: Was thinking one thing, typing another ;)