# Saving a Color to a file (Visual C#)

Tags: c#, colors, save

I am currently working on a program that lets the user save and edit Strings and other Variables, among others colors. Now, I want the user to be able to save all data in the form to a file, but that's not the problem. Is there any way to save the color from a ColorPickerDialog (colorPickerDialog1.Color) to a file? I tried converting it into a string and saving that, but I have no idea how to convert the String back into a color. (I am only using the named colors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET - Converting Color Name Strings into System.Drawing.Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579528/net-converting-color-name-strings-into-system-drawing-color)

Comment: See [ColorTranslator Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Color.FromArgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Color.ToArgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb(v=vs.110).aspx). Those will convert Color objects to/from 32-bit integer values, which you can of course convert to/from string values.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks a lot.